# Go forward in bash argument history

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I know about <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to show the previous argument in bash.

But what if I went past the desired argument (pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> one too many times) and I want to go *forward* in history?

Is there a key combination for that?

Comment: Other than just up and down arrow key's? I mean, that may or may not sound obvious to you, but I just want to be sure.

Comment: @Gravy Argument, not command. M-. and M-_ are bound to the `yank-last-arg` readline command. There's a `yank-nth-arg` on M-C-y, but I'm a `vi` user so I'm not familiar with Emacs key mappings. Heck I don't even have a Meta-key...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> runs readline function `yank-last-arg`:

> yank-last-arg (M-., M-_)
>
> Insert the last argument to the previous command (the last word of the previous   history   entry).    With  a  numeric  argument,  behave  exactly  like
>                 yank-nth-arg.  Successive calls to yank-last-arg move back through  the  history  list, inserting the last word (or the word specified by the argument to
>                 the first call) of each line in turn.  Any numeric argument supplied to these
>                 successive  calls  determines  the  direction to move through the history.  A
>                 negative argument switches the direction through the history  (back  or  forward).   The  history expansion facilities are used to extract the last word,
>                 as if the "!$" history expansion had been specified.

So to reverse its meaning one has to supply a negative argument to it. This can be done via other functions: `digit-argument` or `universal-argument`. The first is easier to use because it is already bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>[[:digit:]]</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> for negative arguments.

So, to go backward in history run <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>. To go forward run <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> and repeat with just <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>. To go backward again, switch directions again with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>.